# json4s, "no implicit view available from List of case class to JValue" when attempting to combine

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I try to generate json by combining some fields, including a Seq of case class.

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.{read, write}

object JsonExample extends App {
  case class CC(eid: String, num: Integer)
  implicit val formats:Formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)

  val json = ("api_key" -> "1234") ~ ("attributes" -> List(CC("123", 123), CC("222", 222)))

  println(write(json))
}
```

But I got compilation errors

Error:(9, 36) No implicit view available from List[JsonExample.CC] => org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue.
  val json = ("api_key" -> "1234") ~ ("attributes" -> List(CC("123", 123), CC("222", 222)))

Error:(9, 36) not enough arguments for method ~: (implicit ev1: List[JsonExample.CC] => org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue)org.json4s.JsonAST.JObject.
Unspecified value parameter ev1.
  val json = ("api_key" -> "1234") ~ ("attributes" -> List(CC("123", 123), CC("222", 222)))

Note, if I remove the combine ~, then it works: 
val json = ("attributes" -> List(CC("123", 123), CC("222", 222)))

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can see in ["Extending the DSL" section](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#dsl-rules), that if you want to add `CC` class support into the DSL you should provide implicit conversion `type DslConversion = CC => JValue`.

So, you should write something like this:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.write

object JsonExample extends App {
    implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)

    case class CC(eid: String, num: Int)
    implicit def ccToJValue(data: CC)(implicit formats: Formats): JValue = Extraction.decompose(data)

    val json = ("api_key" -> "1234") ~ ("attributes" -> List(CC("123", 123), CC("222", 222)))

    println(write(json))
}
```